# Biml not found after installing plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2019, biml

I am new to Biml and I recently installed it using the Manage Extension feature in Visual Studio 2019 but I cannot find it in the bar like below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems that current version of BIMLExpress (5.0.64108.0) isn't compatible with latest Integration Service-Extension from MS.

Download Version 3.16 (noted as last GA-Version) directly from [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects) and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Varigence has stopped providing support for the BIML Engine in BI Developer Extensions. They now have their own BimlExpress extension
Go to the [Varigence website](https://www.varigence.com/bimlexpress) to download the BimlExpress VSIX file, and install it. While opening Visual Studio, you may see a yellow bar with a warning:

[image]

The warning says:

> Visual Studio did not load one or more extensions that were using
>   deprecated APIs.

”Click “Allow synchronous autoload” and restart Visual Studio. BimlExpress will now load without the warning.

**Where did the BimlExpress menu go?**

Another change in Visual Studio is that individual extension menus are now grouped under the main Extensions menu on the toolbar:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately after enabled the deprecated APIs in the yellow bar, I still don't get any BimlExpress functionality. (The toolbar is in the extensions, but nothing else works).

Comment: The Biml express toolbar are disabled, I couldn't click any of its button to use its functionality. Is there any way to access it.